# How to manage memory when I have to use lots of icons in Android?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, drawable, android-memory

I am developing an app. There I have 1200+ icons in `drawable-hdpi` folder. Every second I am picking up a icon which I need to show. All the icons are `48*48` pixel and in `.png` format. They are taking `774 KB` space in total. I am running a `Service` and from there I am choosing the icon every second. And in `onCreate()`of That `Service` I am storing the `drawable` ids like this way:

```
speed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    speed.add(R.drawable.image000);
    speed.add(R.drawable.image001);
    speed.add(R.drawable.image002);
    //...and so on
```

My app is so simple. Its adding some numbers, and takes the icon from corresponding arraylist's room and shows it in the Notification status bar. Like:

```
nm.notify(1, builder.setContentTitle("up: " + s + " down: " + s2)
            .setContentText(g)
            .setSmallIcon(speed.get(xValue + yValue))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setPriority(128)
            .build());
```

So now the problem is, my app taking too much memory`(Arround 105-120 MB)`. I am not using any `Bitmap`. Even I am calling this method in every second in `Service`:

```
public void freeMemory() {
        System.runFinalization();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
        System.gc();
    }
```

and also added this code:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        this.finish();
    }
```

in every activity. So why this much memory? Am I storing those icons in wrong way? What should I do now?

Comment: `I am not using any Bitmap` ... and how do you call your icons (`R.drawable.imagexyz`)? Aren't these bitmaps (png files)?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that picture is bitmap itself. @FrankN.Stein

Answer (score 0):

Well for efficient size, you have 2 options either upload the image online and then take it from there, because now everyone has internet on smartphone so taking images from web is not a bad idea to save a bunch of save (in MBs).

```
String imageUri = "http://example.com/myimage.png"; // from Web
```

OR

the 2nd option is to upload the files on the SD card after installation of the app and then take the file from the SD Card. Both options are efficient. Choose which ever you are continent with.

```
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/myimage.png"; // from SD card
```

Comment: to show them in notification's small icon I must have to put those files in drawable. @Mike

Comment: How does it affect memory issues? I don't think his asking about storage/app size problem.